# Unit Closed ball in ${\it l}^{1} $has empty interior as a subset of ${\it l}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $C = \{ x \in {\it l}^1 : ||x||_{1} \leq 1 \}$ we have that $C \subset {\it l}^{\infty}$, then prove that C has empty interior as a subset of  $ {\it l}^{\infty}$.

My attempt: i take $x = (x_{n}) \in int(C)$, thus there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $y \in {\it l}^{1}$ with $||x-y||_{\infty} < \epsilon$ implies that $y \in C$. My objective is to construct a sequence $z = (z_{n})$ such that  $||x-z||_{\infty} < \epsilon$ thus $z \in C$, but by the other hand $||z||_{1} > 1$, so we get a contradiction. I consider $z_{n} = x_{n} + \frac{1}{n}$ for any $n$, i can prove that $||z||_{1} > 1$, but i can not prove that $||x-z||_{\infty} < \epsilon$.

Can someone give me a suggestion?
Pd: i also prove that $C$ is closed in ${\it l}^{\infty}$, convex and absorbent.
Have a nice day.

Comment: You took $z = x + \langle\frac1n\rangle$, and your problem was that the $\ell_\infty$ norm of $\langle\frac1n\rangle$ is $1$. Maybe you could add something of smaller $\ell_\infty$ norm? Say something of $\ell_\infty$ norm less than $\epsilon$, but which still isn't in $\ell_1$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe hello! Thanks for your answer. I read your comment and i inmediately think in consider $z_{n} = x_{n} + \epsilon / 2$, this sequence works? For instance, it's inmediately that $(z_{n}) \in C$ but i have problems to prove that $||z||_{1} >1$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe or maybe $z_{n} = x_{n} + \frac{\epsilon}{2n}$ works better.

Comment: Every ball in $l^\infty$ is unbounded in $l^1$-normal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $\varepsilon$ be like in the opening post. For a fixed $N$, let
$y^{(N)}\in\ell^1$ be given by $y^{(N)}_j=x_j+\varepsilon/2\mathbf{1}_{1\leqslant j\leqslant N}$. Then $\lVert x-y^{(N)}\rVert_\infty\leqslant\varepsilon_2$ hence we should have that $y^{(N)}\in C$ for each $N$. But by the reversed triangular inequality,
$\lVert y^{(N)}\rVert_1\geqslant N\varepsilon/2-\lVert x\rVert_1$, giving a contradiction with $\lVert y^{(N)}\rvert_1\leqslant 1$ (it sufficed to take $N$ such that $1<N\varepsilon/2-\lVert x\rVert_1$).

Comment: Why the last inequality implies the contradiction? I was thinking this for a couple of hours and i don't why this occurs.

Comment: @Pirry I have edited.

Comment: Okey, I think the following: the contradiction arises because $N$ is arbitrary, since for every $N$, $y^{(N)} \in C$, if we take $N$ large, then obviously $N\epsilon /2 - ||x||_{1}$ > 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with these special sequence spaces: Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces such that $X\subseteq Y$ and the unit ball $B_X$ has $Y$-interior points. Then $X=Y$.

Indeed, for an iterior point $x$ there is $r>0$ such that $B_Y(x,r)\subseteq B_X \subseteq X$. For $y\in Y$ choose $t>0$ such that $\|ty\|_Y<r$. Then $x-ty\in B_Y(x,r)\subseteq X$ and $$ y= \frac 1t \bigg(x-(x-ty)\bigg) \in X.$$